# Unable to drop rows with missing (0) value -Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I tried to drop the row with missing values (0) in them but it didn't work. When I extracted to an excel file, it is still showing a lot of rows with 0 value in my variable GTCBSA. Did I write my drop function incorrectly?

```
for i in range(2004,2007):
   url = f"https://api.census.gov/data/{i}/cps/basic/jun?get=GTCBSA,PEFNTVTY"
   a = pd.read_json(url)
   a = pd.DataFrame(a.iloc[1:,]).set_axis(a.iloc[0,], axis="columns", inplace=False)
   a.dropna(subset = ["GTCBSA"])

a
```

[image]

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, Pandas has a very precise concept of missing values. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isna.html#pandas.Index.isna). In your case, "zero" (0) is not considered a "missing value". Hence, if you have your personal interpretation of what a "missing value" should look like, you need to code the filtering yourself, like in Ynjxsjmh's answer.

Comment: @user2246849 Yes I understood that, I actually tried several filtering (should have clarified in my post), but it didn't work. Just tried Ynhxsjmh's answer too, it didn't work still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using would only give you results if the values are actually missing like being (Nan). Not if the value is 0.

Based on the answers above checking that the value is equal to zero also is not working for you. The only thing I can think of is that the values are maybe strings.

I think you should try something like this:

```
df = df[~(df['GTCBSA'] == '0')]
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df = df[df['GTCBSA'].ne(0)]

# or

df = df[~df['GTCBSA'].eq(0)]
```

Since your column type is object, as I said in the comment, you can use

```py
df = df[df['GTCBSA'].ne('0')]

# or

df = df[df['GTCBSA'].astype(int).ne(0)]
```

Also I have advised you to check the column type in my second comments...

Comment: I just tried this but it didnt work...

Comment: @dspassion Before doing this and after doing this, does output of `df['GTCBSA'].eq(0).any()` changes?

Comment: it gave me the same result..

Comment: @dspassion What's the result? If it is `False`, it means there is no `0` in column. What's the type of column `GTCBSA`, is it object or int?

Comment: It does not show as false. It just ran the code but it is still showing "0 rows". I think it is int in my GTCBSA column, how do I check it?

Comment: @dspassion Could you provide an example `key` value?

Comment: I just edited my thread, it worked without a key value.

Comment: @dspassion The column type is object, either set your dataframe type to int with `df = df.astype(int)` or change the `0` in expression to `'0'`.

Comment: Is there a way to drop them without changing the obj to integer? I have another column 'City' that reads the GTCBSA value to look up the city name in a dictionary. When I change the obj to int, it does not work anymore.

Comment: @dspassion Check the `or` part, change `0` to `'0'`